# printing a matplotlib barplot to a txt file

Tags: python, matplotlib

I've created a bar plot and would like to write it to a txt file. 
Instead of using plt.show(), which just brings up an image, or saving it using plt.savefig(), I would like to write the bar plot to my file

I'm currently opening my txt file and would like to add my marplot to it like below

```
with open('filename', 'w') as f: 
  f.write(some lines) 
  somehow write bar plot here 
  f.write(some more lines)
```

Comment: Have you tried using [plt.savefig()](https://matplotlib.org/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.pyplot.savefig.html) and changing the format to pdf or the format you prefer?

Comment: yes but that saves the plot to a separate file, I would like to add the plot to the txt file

Comment: Could you [edit] the question to give an example of what the text should look like for some given data?

Comment: A matplotlib figure is a graphical representation. A txt file contains characters. It is not clear from the question how those two concepts are to be bridged.